# About enrolling on Apples Developers Programm for iOS

Tags: iphone-developer-program

I have already developed an app for iOS and I want to upload it to AppStore. I am about to buy an Apple developer licence for iOS so I would like to ask some questions to people that are already enrolled in a program like that.

First of all I am an individual programmer, I don't own a company, so I should get the individuals' license currently costing $99. When I submit an application as an individual to AppStore will it show my real name as the company or can I choose whatever name I want?

Secondly the name mentioned above will be the same for every application I upload using this licence?

Thirdly and most important. My application will not be free. However I would like to have a free edition too to show the basic functionality of the paid version. What's the difference between:

- having one application that is free for starters and then you can upgrade and pay?
- having 2 different applications where one would be called light version?

Is it harder for people to crack and put on installous the first option? Because many times I've seen on installous downloading an application but it was without the paid upgrade (maybe I am wrong here, though...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still select a company name which will appear on all your apps and is very difficult to change.

With regards to having a lite version, you may find apple would rather you use the in app purchase upgrade route and may reject one of your versions.
Regardless, the In App Purchase upgrade would be less "crackable" than a paid for full version. Especially if you verify receipts.

Comment: The in app purchase how does exactly work? There should be a button that says upgrade and would navigate to appstore? I dont have an example in mind now. And when you upload the application you define that the application will work with the in app purchase?

Comment: @user1511244 You will make a full version but with the Pro Features disabled. Then, you will have a button in your app named "upgrade to pro". User clicks the button, logs in iTunes and after the purchase the Pro Features will be enabled. Here you have a simple example: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/